Connections between the Classical and Quantum Three-body Problem?
If mathematicians somehow find an exact analytical solution to the three-body problem, would that help solve the Schrödinger equation exactly and analytically for the helium atom?
And more generally, would solving the classical $n$-body problem analytically directly lead to a generalized analytical solution for the Schrödinger equation?
What additional considerations/principles are there between classical and quantum mechanics that must be considered?
Also, is there any current mathematical research being done in this field?

Think about how different the two-body problem is between classical and quantum versions. That should tell you quite a bit.

For current research in this direction, you would probably be interested in quantum chaos. At this point it is quite a large field

It can be proved, not without difficulty, that there is no such analytical solution

There is an "analytical" solution for the three body problem. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/729475/explicit-form-of-sundmans-general-solution-of-three-body-problem . I am not sure it will help with quantum mechanics much, especially since the actual quantum problem has other interactions than the classical three body problem. It is relativistic and the main real world effects are related to spin coupling.

Although some people think physics is all about precision in mathematics, mathematicians will tell you that we're more interested in limited, but useful, approximate methods that can be used to test theories in specific parameter ranges.  This isn't ideal, but it's practical and, ultimately, physics is about measurement and comparison of theory with predictions.  Of course I might just be saying this because I'm not Ed Witten. :-)

The Lambert W function has a generalisation that gives the exact solution to the H2+ molecular ion problem, which is a quantum 3-body problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Generalizations
